# Android: How to dynamically replace a list view with another list view like Instagram with onClick?

Tags: android, listview, replace, instagram

I'm building an android app and I'm trying to replace a list view with another list view if you click a button, like the notifications page on Instagram.  On that page, if you click on the top "following" button it will show you a listview of what your followers have liked. If you click on the "you" button it will show you a listview of what people have liked your photos.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you simply need to `setVisibility` to `visible` for the `listview` you want to show and `gone` to hide `listview` you wants to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by following ways,
1. add Two listviews and can change the visibility as per your requirement.
2. On button click you can load the other data into same list view and can update your adapter in the same list view.

in 1 you have to load two list view at first which will consume more time if data is larger sure you can write a login in asynctask to load list views in background thread.

in 2 you have to update your adapter at the button so you will have to provide some progress bar of dialog for user while you list view is getting update.

You can use either of this whichever suites you best.

Answer (score 0):

Simply , You don't need to switch Listview , you only need to switch adapters .

eg, you can switch to `mFollowingAdapter` when clicked on Following button and switch to `mYouAdapter` when you select "You" tab. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a list, that has a custom adapter.  This adapter will be able to display BOTH views you want to display.

If the data to be displayed is the same format (ie. both have an imageview next to a textview), you are in good shape.

When you want to switch to a different list, get the information you would like to display, replace the data in your the collection backing your list, then notify the list that the data has changed, and it should redraw.

So, this might look like:

1. create ArrayList() with data A
2. setup List, with this data and display
3. replace the ArrayList() with data B
4. call listView.notifyDataSetChanged

You can still do this if the Data A, and Data B have different views, in this case, you would need to handle this logic in your custom adapter.